# AJAX function to detect when session is expired and log out

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have this function that checks if a session in the current tab has expired. However, if I open another tab and log out through there, my current tab won't know and somehow it maintains its session until I access an item from the navigation menu. Is there a way I can improve this by detecting when a user has either logged out or if the users session has expired?

The main issue right now is if they open another tab and just log out from there.

```
function check_if_logged_in(){
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo site_url('Common/CheckSession'); ?>",
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('.loading').show();
        },
        success: function(data){
            if(data==="undefined"||data===null||data===0){
                console.log("logged out");
//                window.location.replace("<?php // echo BASE_URL;?>");
            }else{
                console.log("logged in");
            }
            $('.loading').fadeOut("slow");
        },
    });
}
```

This is my checkSession function

```
public function checkSession(){
        if($this->logged_in()===false){
            echo false;
        }else{
            echo true;
        }
    }
```

this->logged_in() just checks if the session is still active.

I have read about LocalStorage by HTML5. I'm wondering if this will affect mobile devices as the site itself is responsive and I've heard that iOS or some devices don't support LocalStorage.

Comment: you have to call this function at  interval

Comment: This function is called via a click at the moment so when I log out on another tab, I switch back to this tab and click the button. The result is still that the session is active.

Comment: what your ajax call return when session is active and inactive?if your logout function works session shouldn't active

Comment: My Ajax call returns 1 for active and 0 for not active. The problem is browser tabs don't know the status of another tab I think.

Comment: No that's not the way sessions work even if you logout from another tab (keeping this one open) in the same  browser it should reflect immediately on the next ajax call.I believe some problem with your logout code.Check if it's a cache issue using `<?php echo site_url('Common/CheckSession'). '?q='.time(); ?>`

Comment: I have added my CheckSession code as well.

Comment: I don't understand what the time is there for? When I click the button the time still remains the same?

Comment: open site_url('Common/CheckSession');  this url in browser and check output after logout from same page and other pages.it's nice to return some json output from server php instead just true/false

Comment: That url returns true. I have set it to return some text as well. It still returns the text even if the other tab has logged out.

Comment: it seems your logout function doesnt work.you need to debug

Comment: My logout destroys the session and manually removes the session variables though. I can't navigate with the back button. It just forces me back to the login page

Answer (score 0):

You should write a js function which can be accessed in every file. Most probably in your footer.

Then write the below code which will be called at an interval of every 5 seconds(You can change it according to your convinience).

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function () {
        checkSession();
    }, 5000);
});


function checkSession()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "your_session_checking_function",
        success: function (data) {
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            if(data.response != "true")
            {   
                window.location.href = 'redirect to login page';  
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Then according to the result obtained in ajax success you can redirect it to the login page.